# Angularjs jQloud experimental issue at Plunker

Tags: angularjs, plunker

For some experimenting, I need to put this [Angular jQcloud](https://github.com/mistic100/angular-jqcloud) at Plunker. I have put all the necessary codes provided by the plugin, still don't understand why that text cloud hasn't come at plunker. Can you please tell me what I have missed?

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <body>
    <jqcloud words="words" width="500" height="350" steps="7"></jqcloud>  
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-jqcloud']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.words = [/* ... */];
});
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/QCyhxxYG1ODb9Uu3sboh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/UIvU2UqL01H4FbD4bEXm).

You forgot to load jquery and angular-jqcloud scripts. Use angular.js instead of angular.min.js whenever possible, it makes more sense in debuggers that don't support source maps (e.g Firebug). Don't add angular directives to `<html>`, Plunker doesn't like it. Devtools are your best friends ever, especially console and network tabs.